# Converting convex quadratic constraint to linear matrix inequality (LMI)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constrained-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have the quadratic programming problem in $x$

$$\text{Minimize}\;\; x^T\Sigma x$$
$$\hspace{15mm}\text{Subject to}\;\; p^Tx = \frac{1}{n}p^T\boldsymbol{1}$$
$$\hspace{25mm}\boldsymbol{1}^Tx=1$$

where $\Sigma$ is positive semidefinite. I can convert this to an epigraph problem

$$\text{Minimize}\;\; t$$
$$\hspace{16mm}\text{Subject to}\;\; x^T\Sigma x \leq t$$
$$\hspace{43mm} p^Tx = \frac{1}{n}p^T\boldsymbol{1}$$
$$\hspace{32mm}\boldsymbol{1}^Tx=1$$

where one of the constraints is now quadratic. I would like to use the Schur complement in order to convert the first constraint to the requirement that the following matrix is positive semidefinite

\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma^{-1} & x\\
x^T & t
\end{bmatrix}

Unfortunately, $\Sigma$ is only positive semidefinite, and not strictly positive definite, and thus I cannot invert it. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option here is to use the pseudoinverse of $\Sigma$ rather than the actual inverse.  Appendix A of Boyd and Vandenberghe discusses a version of the Schur complement that includes this case.

Another alternative is to find a factorization of $\Sigma$ as

$\Sigma=M^{T}M$ (e.g. by eigenvalue decomposition), and then use the Schur theorem on

$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I  & Mx \\
x^{T}M^{T} & t 
\end{array}
\right].
$

Comment: Does the pseudo-inverse result in a loss in accuracy?  Or is there a specific case of Schur's theorem for the pseudo-inverse?  Also, is this factorization done via Cholesky decomp?  Or are you saying to split its eigen-decomp $M^TDM=(M^T\sqrt{D})(\sqrt{D}M)$?  And if so either runs in O(n^3) correct? so it would become prohibitively expensive for matrices with millions of rows?

Comment: There is a specific case of Schur's theorem using the pseudoinverse- see the reference that I gave.  You can't compute a Cholesky factorization of $\Sigma$ since it is not positive definite, but you can certainly compute an eigenvalue decomposition in $O(n^{3})$ time.  As a practical matter you certainly don't want to use SDP to solve this problem at all- the original formulation as a linearly constrained convex QP is much better solved directly by codes for that problem.

Comment: I guess the problem was that it's not possible to tell the default solver (Convex.jl in Julia) that $\Sigma$ is positive semidefinite, and so it regarded it as not DCP compliant.  Thank you for the detailed responses, this makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: Be aware that some QP codes will work only on problems where the objective is strictly convex.  As a practical matter, you can't really tell numerically whether a matrix is positive semidefinite or indefinite- you may be better off modifying $\Sigma$ just enough to make it obviously PD.

Comment: It should be mentioned that using the pseudo-inverse form of the Schur complement doesn't work in this case, since the requirement that $(\text{I} - \Sigma\Sigma^{\dagger})x=0$ is only satisfied when $\Sigma$ is strictly positive definite (invertible).